# Powerpivot DAX time- counting when a timestamp falls within 1st 30 mins or 2nd 30 mins of an hour

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

say I have a list of users and timestamps.

```
User Time
Tim  6:15PM
Tim  6:17PM
Tim  6:44PM
Tim  3:33PM
Bort 8:00PM
Bort 9:04PM
Bort 9:05PM
```

I want to count, for each user, the number of 30 minute increment they have a timestamp for, within each hour between 5PM and 8 30AM

Result:

```
Tim 2
Bort 2
```

Note that Tim has times at 6:15 and 6:17, this falls within the first 30 minutes of the 6PM hour, therefore it only counts as 1. He has a time at 6:44PM, which comes after 6:30PM, therefore it also counts as 1. Altogether he has 2

Bort has a time in the first half of 8PM but not in the latter half. So he gets 1. He then has two times within 9PM. Altogether he has 2.

Is this too intense to do in Powerpivot/dax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant PM for those last two Bort rows since that's how you referred to it later.

I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

1. Create a calculated column `HalfHour = ROUNDUP(48*TimeStamps[Time],0)`.
2. Create a measure `CountTimeStamps` as below.
3. Put them in a matrix visual with `User` on the rows and `CountTimeStamps` in the values.

---

```
CountTimeStamps =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(TimeStamps[HalfHour]),
            TimeStamps[Time] <= TIMEVALUE("8:30AM") ||
            TimeStamps[Time] >= TIMEVALUE("5PM")
             )
```

Comment: I have a followup question if you don't mind: what if I also had a `date` column, and I wanted to count the half hours for each date (as opposed to the solution, which treats each time as if they happened on the same date)? Hopefully this doesn't completely change the solution.

Comment: @machump If you have the date in the rows or columns of your visual to provide filter context, I don't think this will need to be changed, otherwise you might need to do something extra like create a column that concatenates date and half hour.